# Eloquent model fill non-persistent attributes

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to fill an Eloquent model with attributes from user request. The fillable array is properly set. However, some of these attributes do not have the corresponding database column.  I would like the model's save() method to ignore these attributes when saving.

I found the magic accessors (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) that let you add non-persistent attributes. However, the save() would still include them in the insert query if that attribute(s) is in the fillable array.

The only solution appear to be unsetting the non-persistent attributes (that are in the fillable array) on saving() event of the model. Any other solution better than using the saving() event?

Comment: Have you tried using *guarded* method instead of *fillable*? So you prevent which ones will not be mass assignable and work with the others

Comment: I tried guarded but still the same issue that Eloquent tries to insert all the non-persistent attributes into the table. I tried putting the non-persistent attributes in $appends array (after removing them from fillable) and also provide a default value for these attribute. In that case, the insert will ignore them but now I can not use the accessors methods (getXXXAttribute()). I was reformatting some of the input with the accessors. Also, i can not mass assign as these attributes are not in the $fillable (or implicitly included because of the $guarded)

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: If you define these non-persistent values as your model class attributes, they'll be automatically ignored when saving. So you can set them as `false` or `NULL` as default value.